# Ruby - Reading and editing XML file

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-1.9.3

I am writing a Ruby (1.9.3) script that reads XML files from a folder and then edit it if necessary.

My issue is that I was given XML files converted by [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) but its ouput is a little strange, fo example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XML>
  <item>
      <ID>000001</ID>
      <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
      <SUPPLIER>Supplier name test,
      Coproration</SUPPLIER>
...
```

As you can see the  has and extra CRLF. I dont know why it has this behaviour but I am addressing it with a ruby script. But am having trouble as I need to see either if the last character of the line is "**>**" or if the first is "**<**" so that I can see if there is something wrong with the markup.

I have tried:

```
Dir.glob("C:/testing/corrected/*.xml").each do |file|

puts file

  File.open(file, 'r+').each_with_index do |line, index|

    first_char = line[0,1]

    if first_char != "<"
        //copy this line to the previous line and delete this one?
    end

  end

end
```

I also feel like I should be copying the original file content as I read it to another temporary file and then overwrite. Is that the best "way"? Any tips are welcome as I do not have much experience in altering a files content.

Regards

Comment: I would suggest you to use `nokogiri`.

Comment: As @RubyLovely suggests use an xml gem such as nokogiri. You are trying to process xml as txt which is both not a good idea and seriously ineffecient in terms of wheel re-inventing

Comment: Hum I see, I am not confined to ruby but I will look into Nokogiri. I wished Tidy wouldn't cause such hassle hehe :)

Comment: Regexp: `/^</`, `/>$/`, but what those guys said. Anytime you think "text processing", think "regexp", but anytime you think  "formated text processing", go look for a gem first.

Comment: You can also `line[0]` and `line[-1]` for first and last character.

Comment: Another nice gem you might want to look into for handling xml is ox. Either way don't do it manually :)

Comment: Thank you for all your input, I have found a way to do it manually and will now otpimize it using the suggested gems, thank you all :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does that extra `\n` always appear in the `<SUPPLIER>` node? As others have suggested, Nokogiri is a great choice for parsing XML (or HTML). You could iterate through each `<SUPPLIER>` node and remove the `\n` character, then save the XML as a new file.

```
require 'nokogiri'

# read and parse the old file
file = File.read("old.xml")
xml = Nokogiri::XML(file)

# replace \n and any additional whitespace with a space
xml.xpath("//SUPPLIER").each do |node|
  node.content = node.content.gsub(/\n\s+/, " ")
end

# save the output into a new file
File.open("new.xml", "w") do |f|
  f.write xml.to_xml
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this, although it does not address my issue direclty (it is not always the <SUPPLIER> node, this is very usefull for another task :)

Comment: You could generalize the solution to run `gsub` on the content of every child node of item. For example, you could change `xml.xpath("//SUPPLIER").each do |node|` to `xml.xpath("//item/*").each do |node|`

Comment: Yes, although I did not user the exact same solution as you suggested, it was something similar, therefore, accepted as the answer